# PHP: reload a php include function without reloading the page

Tags: php

I have a page that has a few php include functions, pulling in content from external php files to represent on the page. Like so:

```
<?php
include 'htmlblocks/catalog.php';
?>
```

What I am looking for is a way to reload one of those include functions when a button is clicked.

Is this possible and if so how would I go about doing this?

*The end goal is to have this specific file (the one that is included via php) take parameters from the url to use to select data in a SQL database *

Thanks in advance!

Comment: reload the page with the parameters set?

Comment: What do you mean by "reload the function"?  If your button loads the page then, well, it will load the page.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Yes, so ideally I want the page itself to not reload. Just that specific include function.

Comment: You could send an AJAX request to `htmlblocks/catalog.php` with the relevant parameters?

Comment: @ValentijnvandenHout: Functions don't "reload".  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Ah okay. Will that reload just that section? I have only recently gotten into php so I am not familiar with AJAX yet.

Comment: @David So what happens now is that if the page is opened, the php includes another php file (which on its turn request data from an SQL database). This is perfect and works fine. What I am aiming for now is to have input from a user on that page change the SQL parameters and thus change the content represented by the included php.file. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @ValentijnvandenHout: So have a form on the page which includes those inputs and when the form is posted to the page use them in your database query.  What have you tried and what isn't working?  Including form inputs in a database query is generally covered by PHP tutorials, have you simply not gotten to that part yet?

Comment: @David I have indeed not covered that yet. I finished php in codecademy which I thought to be enough of a base to fulfill my goals but am noticing I might be slacking some knowledge. I have thusfar captured the values of filters being active and want to use these to dynamically change the content by using them in the SQL query. I just have no idea how to go about doing this without reloading the entire page.

Comment: @ValentijnvandenHout: "Without reloading the entire page" isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.  For that you want to look into something called AJAX.  Not every tutorial would cover that, but there are tutorials to be found on Google which specifically focus on PHP and AJAX.  At a high level, what that does is send a request to the PHP file from JavaScript code instead from from the main browser window's UI.  The PHP code executes as normal with any request and returns a response back to that JavaScript code.  Ideally that response is JSON data instead of HTML.

Comment: @David You are right. Question should have been 'without reloading the entire page', not 'with'. Changed it. And thanks for the explanation. I will definitely look into AJAX.